# Update SSH ciphers for linux (ubuntu) in Azure Function

Tags: linux, azure, ssh, azure-functions

I have created an Azure Function to connect to an SFTP server via SSH. The only problem appears to be that needed SSH ciphers are not supported by SSH on the Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS operating system that the Azure Function is running on. So I'd like to know if there's a way to update the SSH ciphers to the ones I need for the Azure Function on that operating system (without using Docker Hub)?

I read somewhere that you can edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config to get this done, but if that's the way forward, then how is it done (bear in mind that I don't think I have direct access to the operating system in the context of the Azure Function unless I'm mistaken)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you heard it correct you need to edit  `edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config` to get this done.You can configure encryption algorithms in the configuration file using the Ciphers keyword; the default is '`AnyStdCipher`'.

**Perform the following steps:**

1.In /etc/ssh/sshd_config (server) and /etc/ssh/ssh_config (client), search for Ciphers. The following is the default configuration:

Copy

```
#Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
```

2.Uncomment this line and replace it with the following value:

Copy

```
Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
```

3.Restart SSH by running the service sshd restart command.

**reference : https://www.netiq.com/documentation/access-manager-45/security-guide/data/ssh-ciphers.html**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question originated from using paramiko in Python where I got an "unknown cipher" error. Since changing the /etc/ssh/ssh_config file in an Azure Function consumption based model appears to be close to impossible, then I ended up using the fabric python library instead of the paramiko library, which worked.